# Java methods does return an object different from its declaration

Tags: java, option-type, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

I have a java method that returns an `Optional<Long>`:

`Optional<Long> findOptionalRelation(String a, String b)`

In the implementation there is a nativeQuery that counts results in a database:

```
  hqlBuilder.append("SELECT count(r.id)");
  hqlBuilder.append(" FROM RELATION r");
  hqlBuilder.append(" WHERE r.a = :a AND r.b = :b");
  final Query<Long> query = this.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery(finalQuery);
            query.setParameter("a", a);
            query.setParameter("b", b);
            return query.uniqueResultOptional();
```

However, when I execute the method test, it returns an `Optional<BigInteger>` instead of an `Optional<Long>`.

After that, I did a test for myself with `Optional<Long> longOpt = Optional.of(new BigInteger("0"));` which of course cannot be cast.

How can I have bypassed the method return without breaking the execution?

Edit: this is the debugger:

[image: Debugger]

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an overloaded version of `createNativeQuery` with `resultClass` parameter. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I use `TypedQuery` for that, because when I use that overload version of `createNativeQuery` I get an `org.hibernate.MappingException`, I dont want an entity, I want a `Number`

Comment: What is the declaration of `createNativeQuery`? Apparently, it allows you to use an arbitrary type argument without constraints. That’s a fundamental design flaw that easily leads to such problems. But some API designers prefer convenience over correctness.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you didn't get a casting issue at runtime is due to type erasure, you can read about this feature on the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) or in other [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens). This mechanism essentially removes the generic type argument at compilation, meaning that at runtime it is not known.